# How to move left and right through characters of a string, counting whenever a specific character appear?

Tags: javascript, string

If I have a road as a string S, and each character in S is:

```
 "<" -> car going to the left 
 ">" -> car going to the right 
 "." -> speed camera
```

How can I count the total number of times a car pass by a speed camera? Considering that a car going to the right only passes cameras to its right, and cars going to the left only passes cameras to its left.

The test asks me to write a function: `function solution(S);`
that, given a string S of length N, returns the total number of times that cars pass by a camera.
Example:

```
Given S = ".>..." , the function should return 3.
Given S = ".>.<.>" , the function should return 4.
Given S = ">>>.<<<" , the function should return 6.
```

I was trying to solve this in Javascript using 2 pointers, but got stuck and ran out of time.
Any advice? What would be a good method to resolve this in Javascript?

Thank you.

Comment: "was trying to solve this in Javascript using 2 pointers" - please also add your Code Example

Comment: I was setting up let count = ; let left = 0; let right = s.length - 1; while(left < right){ if(s[left] == ">"){left++}} else if (s[left] == "."){count++, left++} .... and I did similar thing with the right side, but decreasing right with each iteration.
My issue was that I could not figure out how to count the "." when left > right. 
I think my mistake was setting up a while loop with left < right, but I am not sure how to do it differently. It might be that a while loop is not even appropriate to resolve this problem in the first place. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a two-pass, one counts the number of times left-going cars passed by cameras while the other counts that for right-going cars. Time complexity is O(n).

```js
function solution(s) {
    let res = 0;
    for (let i = 0, cnt = 0; i < s.length; ++i)
        if (s[i] == '.') cnt++;
        else if (s[i] == '<') res += cnt;
    
    for (let i = s.length-1, cnt = 0; i >= 0; --i)
        if (s[i] == '.') cnt++;
        else if (s[i] == '>') res += cnt;
    return res;
}

console.log(solution(".>..."));
console.log(solution(".>.<.>"));
console.log(solution(">>>.<<<"));
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! It does work perfectly! I do not understand what "res += cnt" is exactly doing. The if statement increment cnt by 1 each time it finds a "." . However, if it finds a "<" or ">", I know it is moving forward / backward, but it is not clear how that piece of coding is accomplishing it.  Would you mind explaining? I appreciate.

Comment: @FePaiva `cnt` is a running count of the number of `.`. Each time you get to a `<` or `>` you add the current count for that car.

Comment: @FePaiva When scanning left to right, each time you encounter a left-going car, you know that it will cross all cameras you have encountered thus far, so you just need to keep track of "number of cameras encountered thus far" to know how many cameras the current left-going car will encounter instead of having to do an inner loop to trace back that number everytime.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Barmar and bui! Appreciate the time to explain the solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested loops. The main loop looks for `<` and `>` characters. When it sees one of these, it does a second loop counting the number of `.` characters before or after it, adding this to the total.

```js
function solution(s) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i] == '<') {
      for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (s[j] == '.') {
          count++;
        }
      }
    } else if (s[i] == '>') {
      for (let j = i + 1; j < s.length; j++) {
        if (s[j] == '.') {
          count++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(solution(".>..."));
console.log(solution(".>.<.>"));
console.log(solution(">>>.<<<"));
```

This is the simple solution, not very efficient (it's O(n^2)). So if you're trying to do this for a code challenge site, it might get a time limit exceeded failure.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Barmar. There was no specification about time efficiency. I was trying to get to your solution on my first attempt, but I got confused as I did not added a nested loop. It is clear for me how your code works now. Appreciate your support.